# PHPStorm and mixed line ending

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a php file in this file I have mixed line ending. 
Example: 1-3 lines use \n and 4-10 lines use \r\n. I know that It is bad.
I have a problem when I try to edit this file using PHPStorm. PHPStorm automatically convert all \r\n to \n.
Is it possible to turn off this feature ?

Comment: If it only converts from `\r\n` to `\n` what would be the problem? Wouldn't you end up with a file only using `\n` linebreaks in this case.

Comment: I would also have to question why you want to use mixed line endings. Perhaps you should consider what you're trying to achieve and code accordingly.

Comment: *"Is it possible to turn off this feature ?"* -- Nope -- IDE will convert all line endings to the ones detected from first few lines. You better use some another text editor (e.g. Notepad++ on Windows) for such files.